# Strange empty bar above fragment on BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnavigationview

This is how it is supposed to look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bLy5.png

This is how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSUjF.png

Strange white `space appears` on top of my `fragment` and moves everything down in an offset of it's height. Tried all the solutions mentioned in similar questions but none help. I am not using `ActionBar`.

Here is the `fragment activity` code:

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

private SearchView searchView;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;

public SearchFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment SearchFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static SearchFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    SearchFragment fragment = new SearchFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_search, container, false);
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    searchView = getView().findViewById(R.id.searchView);
    recyclerView = getView().findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);

    recyclerAdapter =  new RecyclerAdapter();

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));

    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

Fragment xml code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SearchFragment">

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/search_shape"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryHint="Pretrazite proizvode..."
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.05" />
```

This constraint layout has a closing tag but it does not appear like it here.
Say if you need more code to find out the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the UI

Comment: Added, sorry forgot about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found!

The problem was in the layout of the Activity that holds the fragment and navigation. Somehow a property for top padding was automatically set to the value of AcitonBar height.

Comment: to be more specific: just delete the `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` at the constraintLayout

Answer (score 0):

I think a problem hiding here:

```
<SearchView
android:id="@+id/searchView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/search_shape"
android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
android:queryHint="Pretrazite proizvode..."
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" <--- here 
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Can you try to remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

find this code `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` in your xml file (the one contains BottomNavigationView) and delete it.